# Pl/sql stored procedure in fluent nhibernate

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using fluent nhibernate and I cannot use stored procedure and excute it.

I tried:

```
Session.GetNamedQuery("Select_All_Question_Groups");
```

and:

```
const string sql = "EXEC [dbo].[Stored_Procedure_Name] @PortalId=:PortalId";
return _session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).SetInt32("PortalId", portalId)
```

---

```
const string sql = "call [dbo].[Stored_Procedure_Name] @PortalId=:PortalId";
return _session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).SetInt32("PortalId", portalId)
```

---

```
const string sql = "EXEC [dbo].[Stored_Procedure_Name](PortalId=:PortalId)";
return _session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).SetInt32("PortalId", portalId)
```

But none of those options works.
when I use session.GetNamedQuery() I got error that the procedure does not exist.
In the other options there is no error, but the procedue does not change anything.

Comment: try to run the generated query manually. There is probably a typo or something like this

Comment: It works manually, I Cannot do this on C#.Another suggestions?

Comment: try `var cmd = session.Connection.CreateCommand(); cmd.CommandText = "..."; cmd.Type = CommandType.StoredProcedure; cmd.ExecuteNoneQuery();`

Comment: then there is something really off because if ADO.NET can't do it, no ORM can. My last idea is to check if there is a transaction rollback after executing the sproc